# Row-wise or column-wise ordering?

Tags: android, tables, ios, ordering

I noticed that the Messenger app in iOS and Android orders the emoji differently: column-wise vs row-wise, respectively.

I tried searching their guidelines but could not find any reference to the preferred ordering.

Is this something usual ? Should I follow this design in my own app (column-wise on iOS version) ? What factors drive this decision ?

Possibly more opinion-based: what would be some advantages of using one over the other ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Research on eye-movement on a screen tells us that people scan the screen in a **Z**-like pattern (top-left->top-right, top-right->to bottom-left and then bottom-left->bottom-right)

This is a rule of thumb when it comes to placing items on the screen. According to that rule, **horizontal grouping makes more sense** as it follows the user's eye.

Here are some good articles about human eye tracking:

- http://www.creativebloq.com/ux/how-human-eye-reads-website-111413463
- https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-the-z-layout-in-web-design--webdesign-28

Comment: Thank you ! I think I've read about the z-like scan pattern, but can't find the research. Do you happen to have a link ? 

I think this answers the most important part of the question: _which one should I use?_

Comment: Added reference links

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shreyas' answer: horizontal grouping is more natural in general. It's the way many parts of the world read.

However, the iOS emoji UI likely takes a column approach because it scrolls horizontally. Otherwise, the organization would be completely broken.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! This is a very good observation that I couldn't figure myself ! It does make sense